# Trouble viewing API Gateway CloudWatch logs and enabling through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to build my architecture, specifically an API Gateway with CloudWatch Logs integration. However, I am encountering an issue where I cannot see the API Gateway CloudWatch logs. I have integrated the apigateway-sns and can see the Lambda logs subscribed to the SNS topic, but I am unable to view the CloudWatch logs for the API Gateway methods.

From the console, I noticed that the "CloudWatch Logs" option is unchecked. I can manually check it from the console, but I want to configure it through Terraform. I have checked my Terraform code, but I can't figure out where I am making a mistake.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "main" {
  name        = "gitlab-slack-api-${var.environment}"
  description = "Gitlab Slack notifications integration"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "main_api_gw" {
  name              = "/aws/api-gw/${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.name}"
  retention_in_days = 14
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "resource" {
  path_part   = "slack"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.root_resource_id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.querystring.TopicArn" = false
    "method.request.querystring.Message"  = false
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  type                    = "AWS"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${data.aws_region.region.name}:sns:action/Publish"
  credentials             = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_role.arn

  request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.querystring.TopicArn" = "'${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic_name.arn}'"
    "integration.request.querystring.Message"  = "method.request.body"
  }

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<EOF
   {
      "Message": "$input.body",
      "TopicArn": "$input.params('TopicArn')"
   }
   EOF
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "integration_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_integration.integration]
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  stage_name  = var.environment
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "prod" {
  depends_on    = [aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment]
  stage_name    = var.environment
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.id

  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.main_api_gw.arn
    format = jsonencode({
      requestId        = "$context.requestId"
      requestTime      = "$context.requestTime"
      requestTimeEpoch = "$context.requestTimeEpoch"
      path             = "$context.path"
      method           = "$context.httpMethod"
      status           = "$context.status"
      responseLength   = "$context.responseLength"
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "all" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test_api_gateway.id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.prod.stage_name
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    logging_level = "INFO"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_gateway_sns_policy" {
  name        = "ApiGatewaySNSAccessPolicy"
  description = "IAM policy for API Gateway to invoke SNS"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
         Effect   = "Allow"
         Action   = ["sns:Publish"]
         Resource = aws_sns_topic.sns_topic_name.arn
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "api_gateway_role" {
  name = "ApiGatewaySNSAccessRole"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
     Statement = [
       {
          Effect    = "Allow"
          Principal = { Service = "apigateway.amazonaws.com" }
          Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
     ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "api_gateway_role_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.api_gateway_sns_policy.arn
}

output "api_gateway_endpoint_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.invoke_url
}

output "api_gateway_endpoint_arn" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.arn
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, the IAM role assigned to the API Gateway does not have permissions to write to log groups.

Comment: where should I give the permission?

Comment: In the permissions policy of the IAM role assigned to the API Gateway. However, a better approach may be to create the log group from the UI and import it into state.

Comment: thank you @MarkoE, I am learning Terraform. it would be nice to learn from how to implement in Terraform than Console :)

Comment: I've told you only what's written in the documentation as well. Is there a stage that you are using for your API Gateway? There is a resource for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging for API Gateway in the Stage settings, for which a terraform resource exists. Based on the example from the documentation and your code, the following should enable you to configure logging:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "main_api_gw" {
  name              = "API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id}/${var.environment}"
  retention_in_days = 14
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "main" {
  stage_name = var.environment

  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.main_api_gw.arn
    format = "JSON" # or CLF/XML/CSV
  }
}
```

In order to avoid circular dependency, you would need to define the stage name as a variable, which in your case seems to be `var.environment`. This is a part of the log group `name` argument and `stage_name` argument of the API Gateway stage resource. Additionally, [the name of the log group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_stage#managing-the-api-logging-cloudwatch-log-group) has to be like this, as this is the default API Gateway naming convention:

> To manage the CloudWatch Log Group when this feature is enabled, the `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` resource can be used where the name matches the API Gateway naming convention.

The `format` argument is required and can take in one of `"JSON"/"XML"/"CLF"/"CSV"`, which you can read more about in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html).

---

EDIT: Since the original post didn't show all the code, and the stage resource was present, referencing the log group properly, what would need to change is the log group name (as described above) and the IAM role permissions. Besides having SNS allowed in the permissions policy, CloudWatch logs also need to be added:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_gateway_sns_policy" {
  name        = "ApiGatewaySNSAccessPolicy"
  description = "IAM policy for API Gateway to invoke SNS"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
         Effect   = "Allow"
         Action   = ["sns:Publish"]
         Resource = aws_sns_topic.sns_topic_name.arn
      },
      {
         Effect   = "Allow"
         Action   = [
           "logs:CreateLogGroup",
           "logs:CreateLogStream",
           "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
           "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
           "logs:PutLogEvents",
           "logs:GetLogEvents",
           "logs:FilterLogEvents"
         ]
         Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you  . what is difference  `aws_api_gateway_stage` and `aws_api_gateway_deployment` when I tried to create `aws_api_gateway_stage` with same environment then it throws error: "creating API Gateway Stage (prod): ConflictException: Stage already exists.". why do I have create another `stage`? here is code sample:

https://codeshare.io/xvBmMX

Comment: So you didn't add all the code you have to the question?

Comment: I have added all the code. tried one approach based on Terraform doc, in order to populate logs to CloudWatch. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.6.0/docs/resources/api_gateway_stage

Comment: Where is the code from the URL coming from then?

Comment: In stackoverflow comments' code looks terrible thats why I used code share url. here is all code: https://codeshare.io/xvBmMX

Comment: Yeah, so the entire block with the stage is missing from the original post. That's why you are getting an error with multiple stages. I wasn't aware it was there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254434/discussion-between-krisna-and-marko-e).

Comment: @Krisna I have edited the answer, adding the part of the policy that is required to allow API Gateway to write to a log group.

Comment: Thank you, Last 3 and half hours I have keep getting this error: 
`Error: updating API Gateway Stage (ags-204lm87ouj-prod): BadRequestException: CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging`

Comment: I have tried to attach the role arn via console but no luck. getting this error:
 `BadRequestException: The role ARN does not have required permissions configured. Please grant trust permission for API Gateway and add the required role policy.` I will check 2moro, whats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
ApiGate needs a role to allow CloudWatch to publish logs, some how Marko's policy did not work(don't why). I have used the AWS managed role [AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html)  and the resource aws_api_gateway_method_settings for enabling the logs(INFO, ERROR,OFF). Now I can see the API Gateway logs in CloudWatch.

Thank you Marko, put some effort on the issue.

Here is Terraform:

```js
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_integration.integration]
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "prod" {
  depends_on    = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.main_api_gw]
  stage_name    = var.environment
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.id

  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.main_api_gw.arn
    format = jsonencode({
      requestId        = "$context.requestId"
      requestTime      = "$context.requestTime"
      requestTimeEpoch = "$context.requestTimeEpoch"
      path             = "$context.path"
      method           = "$context.httpMethod"
      status           = "$context.status"
      responseLength   = "$context.responseLength"
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "api_gateway_cloud_watch_role" {
  name = "AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs"

  assume_role_policy = <<-EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow"
        }
      ]
    }
  EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "api_gateway_cloudwatchlogs" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_cloud_watch_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "api_gateway_account" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_cloud_watch_role.arn
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "api_gateway_log_settings" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  stage_name  = var.environment
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level   = "INFO"
  }
}
```

Ref:

Took Ref from [here](/https://github.com/darren-reddick/terraform-aws-transfer/blob/master/apigateway.tf) as well